# Jasper fill report using jsonql datasource in Java

Tags: java, json, jasper-reports

We designed a new report using json data with jsonql as the query language and multiple sub report levels that generates fine in Jaspersoft studio (v6.6.0).

We need some java code to take the generated json data and create a report using precompiled jasper files on server, running Jasper 6.6.0 on server, however when we try to generate the pdf's in java, some sub reports crash saying it cant find the data to use and when we remove those problematic sub reports, it generates a mostly blank file with 1 or 2 headings and no relevant information/tables are shown.

```
    InputStream jasperTemplateStream = getReportingTemplate();

    JRDataSource jsonDataSource = new JsonQLDataSource(request);

    JasperReport jasperReport = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(jasperTemplateStream);

    JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, null, jsonDataSource);

    JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint, response);
```

Any ideas as to why? Our Jaspersoft Studio and Jasper `mvn` versions are the same.

The stacktrace is as follows:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRExpressionEvalException: Error evaluating expression for source text: ((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonQLDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("assetClasses") 
...
Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRExpressionEvalException: Error evaluating expression for source text: ((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonQLDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("assetClasses")
...
Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: No JSON data to operate on!
```

Comment: Have you checked if `request` variable isn't empty?

Comment: What do you mean by `populated with a jasper template`? From my understanding it should contain the json file - your data source.

Comment: Sorry @Amongalen, the `request` variable is populated with json data.

Comment: @Amongalen the `"assetClasses"` is in our Json data.

Comment: Do you have a jsonql query in the report?  If so, you would need to do (assuming request to be an InputStream):  
Map<String, object> params; params.put(JsonQueryExecuterFactory.JSON_INPUT_STREAM, request);
JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, params);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing the data input stream to the fillReport() method, try passing it through in the parameter map instead:

```
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put(JsonQLQueryExecuterFactory.JSON_INPUT_STREAM, request);
JasperReport jasperReport = (JasperReport) 
JRLoader.loadObject(jasperTemplateStream);
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, params);
JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint, response);
```

Comment: This worked for me. It lead me to another issue with a missing library, found the library and problem is solved.